# Display the value of text on p item when the event onfocus is triggered.

Tags: javascript, html, onfocus

I would like to display the value of the text field on the p item when the event onfocus is triggered. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
<input type="text" id="test1" name="test2" value="hello" onfocus="myFunction()">
    <p id="test3"></p>

function myFunction() {
    var x=document.getElementByID("test1").value;
    document.getElementByID("test3").innerHTML=x;
}
```

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/d25387um/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementByID` is the incorrect case. Replace it everywhere with `getElementById` (note lowercase `d` as the last character.

Comment: Yes it does. It doesn't work in your fiddle because you have the code in the `onload` section. Move it to `nowrap in <body>` or `<head>`. https://jsfiddle.net/hv253fq7/